# Otel Collectors

Tags: open-telemetry-collector, otel

What are the next steps to create docker image from this Build from source:
You can build the latest version of the Collector based on the local operating system using the following commands:

git clone https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector.git
cd opentelemetry-collector
make install-tools
make otelcorecol

I am trying to create docker image from source code binary